# import str and number columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a simple demonstration code. I expect dtypes as`{'a':str, 'b':str, 'c':int, 'd':float}`, especially, str `b` is honored as the input.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

s = """a,b,c,d
a1,,1,1.2
a2,00,,3.3
a3,01,3,2.3
a4,10,4,1.3"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
df

    a   b   c   d
0   a1  NaN 1.0 1.2
1   a2  0.0 NaN 3.3
2   a3  1.0 3.0 2.3
3   a4  10.0    4.0 1.3
```

Not what I expect (column `b` is wrong).

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=str, na_filter=False)
df

    a   b   c   d
0   a1      1   1.2
1   a2  00      3.3
2   a3  01  3   2.3
3   a4  10  4   1.3
```

Looks correct, but failed when converting column `c` to int or float.

```py
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(int)

---------------------------------------------------------
ValueError            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3903327/3842575137.py in <module>
      1 df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=str, na_filter=False)
----> 2 df['c'] = df['c'].astype('float')
      3 #df['d'] = df['d'].astype(float)
      4 df

...

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The following code gives the same error

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),
                 dtype={'a':str, 'b':str, 'c':int, 'd':float},
                 na_filter=False)
df
```

Comment: What is the expected output? There is no missing `int` value in pandas. If you want missing values it has to be float since `NaN` is a float. If you want it to be an empty space then the dtype must be object.

Comment: How do you convert an empty string to int? The `np.int` data type does not allow NaN, `np.float` does. This works for me: `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=',', dtype={'a':str, 'b':str, 'c':float, 'd':float})`

Comment: @HenryEcker I expect {'a':str, 'b':str, 'c':int, 'd':float}, so empty str `''`, zeros str `'00', '01'` should be kept as the input.

Comment: `c` _cannot_ be an int unless you specify what whole number should be in place of the empty string `''`. And if you don't want nan replacement in `b` you're going to have to read in all as a string `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=str, na_filter=False)` then convert... Or you could `fillna` after. But this is a lot of post processing on a csv. There's likely a better way to save the df than text if we need these varied dtypes that cannot be inferred from text.

Comment: @CodeDifferent missing numeric values can be filled with `nan`. The automatic datetype inference (without `dtype` specified) is `object, float, float, float`, but I expect `str, str, int, float`

Comment: "missing numeric values can be filled with nan" --> here lays your problem. `np.int` does not allow nan. You have to change column `c` to float or insert some sentinel value (like -1) to represent "emptiness"

Comment: @CodeDifferent  `df['c'] = df['c'].astype('float')` gives error too

Comment: @HenryEcker I totally agree with u, but csv files were downloaded from website. Read all as str and converting using `.astype` raises error as above.

Comment: You _could_ use 'Int32' or 'Int64' which allows NA but depends on your downstream process, you might want to convert to regular `int` at some point.

`df = pd.read_csv(..., dtype={..., 'c': 'Int32', ...})     df.c.fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: @Emma yes, 'Int32' works. Can you make an A and give more explanations on why it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because regular `int` data type is not nullable and your data includes the null value.

To work with the nullable value, Pandas has an [extension types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-extension-types). Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64 are the extension of integer type, called [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html). The null value will be replaced with null-like value  (pd.NA).

In order to use these extension types for `read_csv`, you can pass with `dtype`. Pick any of "IntXX" variation that is appropriate for your data.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), header=0, dtype={'a': str, 'b': str, 'c': 'Int32', 'd': float})
```

You can later convert to regular `int` using `astype`.

```
df['c'] = df.c.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

For more operations with the nullable integer type, please refer to the link above.