# How to keep data types when reading from s3 bucket using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Im using a Lambda function to read a csv from s3 and insert the data into a table. When reading from s3 I've noticed that when I read it to disk and the read it in pandas any field that an int and starts with a `0` is getting turned into a float and any leading `0` is getting removed. How do keep the int values as ints when reading from s3 bucket?

for example if I have a field `account_number` with the value `012345678` when I read in from s3 it becomes `1234567.0`, turning my integer to `Float64`. This is causing downstream problems. How do I get around this issue.

Sample code:

```
export_csv = client.get_object(Bucket = s3_bucket, Key = bo_file_name)
bo_body = export_csv['Body']
csv_string = bo_body.read().decode('utf-8')
bo_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), sep = '|', quotechar = '"')
#Replacing NaN values with Nulls.
print('removing nulls from df')
bo_df.fillna('', inplace = True)
sql_server = os.getenv('DB_ENDPOINT')
```

sample schema after reading into `pandas`:

```
first_name                                object
middle_initial                            object
last_name                                 object
date_of_birth                             object
actnum                                   float64
```

Comment: If there is null value in `actnum` column, pandas will convert it to `float` because `int` cannot be nullable.  You could use nullable extension type, `Int16` or `Int32` if that works.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70014282/2956135

Comment: There are times where it may be `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your account 'number' is really a string that happens to be all numeric (if that makes sense) - it has no mathematical meaning, but pandas thinks it does, so it's treating it as a float.

The solution is to tell Pandas which datatype to use, to over-ride its (usually) good intention of inferring it.

Here's a reproducible walkthrough:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ["01", "02", "03", "10", "11", "", None]
someDF = pd.DataFrame(data)
someDF.to_csv("accts.csv", index=False)
```

Now read it back:

```
pd.read_csv("accts.csv")
```

You get this:

```
    0
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   10.0
4   11.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
```

Not what you had in mind.

Now try it by specifying the datatype explicitly:

```
importedDF = pd.read_csv("accts.csv", names=["Account"], header=0, dtype=str).fillna(value="")
print(importedDF)

     Account
0    01
1    02
2    03
3    10
4    11
5      
6
```

Notes:

- some good info here on the background of the problem of integer columns with nulls getting auto-converted to floats: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html
- if you pass in a dict of column names and datatypes, you can pick and choose for which columns to control the datatype - details are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thank you! I'm testing now and will let you know if I get stuck or if it works.